# Are entity and DTO always mandatory for DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am new to Domain Driven Design. Currently I have around 5 beans with a hierarchy between them. The beans strictly speaking are DTOs. However I would be returning them from the domain layer to the service layer and to the controller. This has been working fine for me, however as per Domain Driven Design, Domain layer must return BOs and service must return a DTO or BO which the controller will map to the DTO. I don't see the point of this since finally I would be converting the object the service returns to JSON which is only data. So is it really necessary for me to have separate BOs and DTOs.

Note that I have a stateless Business Object which performs all the operations for a particular business functionality and return multiple DTO's as required. Kindly do advise if I am on the right path.

Comment: Which would you remove then, Entities or DTO's?

Comment: I would be removing entities

Comment: DDD without entities makes no sense. Read up on it (ideally, one of the books) and you'll understand why.

Comment: The entities here are business objects with no business logic. The business logic is seperate. I have read on Domain Driven Design and I know that you need entities. But from the way I see it I think that having business logic within an entity could cause problems. For example lets take Student as an entity. Now if I want to get a list of students, that logic cannot be there within this entity. Hence I would need to write this logic elsewhere which means that from some other layer I would need to get the data from the database. Now the student entity is accessing the database.

Comment: Along with another layer hence that database is getting accessed from two layers while ideally only entities should be accessing the database with the service applying the transactions.

Comment: I am aware that most DDD documents state that you should use domain entities with VOs and VOs need to be converted to a DTO . But in this case I see having a business object with no logic(like a DTO) with the business logic as a stateless entity makes more sense.

Comment: Getting students is a job for StudentRepository, whose interface is defined in the Domain layer but implemented in the Persistence layer. All of that is described in the books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126142/discussion-between-prashant-and-guillaume31).

Answer (score 0):

> is it really neccassary for me to have seperate BOs and DTOs.

Necessary?  No, the DDD police are not going to come knocking on your door.

But the principle of *separation of concerns* tells us that they should be treated differently.

The business objects are part of the model; they are responsible for ensuring that the data in the model satisfies the business invariant.

DTOs (or to be more accurate -- your representations) are part of the API; they are language agnostic messages that can be shared with other applications.

One key idea here is that because the business objects are part of the model, we expect to support changing them aggressively to meet the needs of the business.  But that's not true of the API, where we want stability so that we don't need to rewrite client code every time we optimize the business model.

Another perspective is that your representations are expected to cross the trust boundary, where your business objects are used to enforce it.  Andreas Hallberg has a good talk on this [(slides)](https://gotocon.com/dl/goto-cph-2015/slides/AndreasHallberg_SecureCodingPatterns.pdf)

> But in this case I see having a business object with no logic

This sounds a lot like you are falling into the trap of an [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).  I'd recommend you review your materials again; if you have concerns about too many entities in your model talking to the database, then you have lost the plot somewhere: the domain model doesn't talk to the database at all.

Comment: Ok so as far as I understand the domain layer should have all operations which do not need a database call but can happen in the application layer. In my current application I do not have many business rules and very few validations. This application is more of a application which maintains a queue of tasks and updates data of the task once a task is completed. There are some validations when data is submitted but thats it.

Comment: So in this case I would be adding the validations to the domain objects and all DB calls would be made from the service and a domain object would be created in the service to ensure data integrity. One question however still remains, I am planning to send all the data in json/xml format. In this case do I need a DTO or can I simply convert to Domain object to json/xml. The parsers would ignore the business logic methods and concentrate only on the getters making it kind of a DTO. Is this approach fine ?